# How can I create a super-dense (2.5 LEDs per cm) addressable strip?

Tags: arduino, led, heat

I'm working on a little project to create an educational device.  For this, I want to be able to have a line of LEDs about 7-8cm long and be able to turn each light on and off.

But the resolution needs to be pretty fine, so they need to be tiny, and very close together.

The maximum density I've found in commercially available LED strips are 144/m which is about 1/2 what I need.

It doesn't need to be flexible or RGB, just single color.

Thanks!

Comment: Make your own pcb then?

Comment: As @PlasmaHH says, roll your own. This density would be easy enough to achieve with hand tool friendly 0805 or 0603 LEDs and SOIC shift registers.

Comment: Will the learning experience be ruined by not having the right density?

Comment: A diffuser will make them look closer together.

Answer (score 1):

**400/m**

[10 Segment Light Bar Graph LED Display](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1816)

[image: 10 Segment Light Bar Graph LED Display]

---

This one is not a strip but has a density of 400/m

[Adafruit 0.8" 8x16 LED Matrix FeatherWing Display Kit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3153)

[image: 10 Segment Light Bar Graph LED Display]

---

Comment: This is simply a shopping question/answer at this rate.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken the SMD soldering challenge?

You can solder 0603 SMD LEDs onto a standard 0.1" (2.54mm) pitch protoboard at this density and pop on a pin header to control each LED.